# Выбрать наименьшее значение из повторящихся

Tags: php

Имеется массив

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => 8711700870658
        [price] => 222.59
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => 4620000432944
        [price] => 8
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => 4620000432944
        [price] => 11
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => Array
            (
                [0] => 7640139350527
                [1] => 3700971301942
                [2] => 7640149641431
                [3] => 3700971302000
                [4] => 4620000432944
                [5] => 3700971301973
            )

        [price] => 74.5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [barcode] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4620000432944
            )

        [price] => 9
    )
```

)

Поле `barcode` может быть как массивом, так и строкой. Необходимо оставить наименьшее `price`, у повторяющихся `barcode`, то есть в данном случае будет так:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [barcode] => 8711700870658
            [price] => 222.59
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [barcode] => 4620000432944
            [price] => 8
         )
    )
```

Мои попытки

```
$returnArray = [];
    foreach ($mergedItems as $item) {
        if( ($key = array_search($item['barcode'], array_column($returnArray, 'barcode'))) === false ) {
            $returnArray[] = $item;
        } else {
            if($item['price'] < $mergedItems[$key]['price']) {
                $returnArray[$key] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Но данный подход не работает, если barcode это массив

Comment: если я правильно понял, можете получить самое меньшее значение из массива  - min($data[barcode])

Comment: Но штрих-код `8711700870658` в исходном массиве не повторяется. Почему он попал в результат?

Comment: Почему были проигнорированы оставшиеся штрихкоды в массиве? из-за наличия там ..944?

Comment: что сделать то надо по итогу, выбрать только те, которые по 2 и более раз и оставить минимальную, либо вы брать все что есть, а у дублей оставить минимум?

Comment: @teran, как и 658 =) Подозреваю, что просто нужно получить меньшую цену по каждому штрихкоду..

Comment: @vp_arth ага, похоже на то.

Comment: Все правильно, по каждому ШК оставить наименьшее значение price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> по каждому ШК оставить наименьшее значение price

Если больше нет никаких нюансов, то такой вариант:

```
$tmp = [];
$result = [];
foreach($arr as $item) {
    foreach((array)$item['barcode'] as $barcode) {
        $tmp[$barcode][] = $item['price'];
    }
}
foreach($tmp as $barcode => $prices) {
    $result[] = [
        'barcode' => $barcode,
        'price' => min($prices)
    ];
}
print_r($result);
```